# Send a huge json as a stream using Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am new to Spring WebFlux and WebClient. I am working on a PoC where I have to send a huge JSON (> 100 MB) as a stream from microservice A to B using a **POST request**. The current implementation sends the **entire json as the request body** which leads to memory spikes on both the ends. Following is the structure of the JSON:

```
{
   "bindings":  {
      "entity1": {

      },
      "entity2": {

      }
   },
   "artifacts": {
      "types": {
         "type1": {

         },
         "type2": {

         }
      },
      "action": {
         "action1": {

         },
         "action2": {

         }
      }
   }
}
```

entity1, entity2 have identical structure. Same applies for type1, type2 and action1, action2 respectively. These objects are **huge** in size with multiple nestings and there can be hundreds of them.

After going through multiple documentation, I have developed the following algorithm for JSON streaming:

1. Convert the JSON object to DataBuffer object, since as per the [link](https://www.amitph.com/spring-webclient-large-file-download/) conversion to DataBuffer helps in chunking.
2. Create a flux from the DataBuffer object.
3. Send the `dataBufferFlux` as the response body in the following way:

```
         WebClient.create("http://localhost:9002/registry")
                    .post()
                    .uri("/packages")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(dataBufferFlux, DataBuffer.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                    .block();
```

Using content-type as `MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON` since `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON` is deprecated.

I have two questions:

1. Is the algorithm correct to do JSON streaming using webclient?
2. If the algorithm is correct, then what is the process of converting a `JSONObject` to `Flux<DataBuffer>` ?

Comment: dont block in a reactive application.

Answer (score 1):

One way to transform the JSON file into a Flux would be:

```
public Flux<DataBuffer> test(String fileName) {
    Path p = Paths.get(new File(basePath + fileName).getAbsolutePath());
    DataBufferFactory dbf = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
    Flux<DataBuffer> flux = DataBufferUtils.read(p, dbf, 256 * 256);
    return flux;
}
```

or another way:

```
public Flux<DataBuffer> test(final JsonObject jo) {
    final DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
    final byte[] bytes = jo.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final DataBuffer buffer = bufferFactory.allocateBuffer(bytes.length);
    buffer.write(bytes);
    return Flux.just(buffer);
}
```

**Alternate approach**

As a sidenote: I would really encourage you to consider a different approach to sending files of that size over a rest interface. The load you put on rest server, rest client and other components that might be involved (network, api gateways, load balancers, cpu, memory etc) could cause severe problems.

Instead, a better tool to share files of this size would be a blob storage (S3 or similar) or a simple file system that is available to all parties involved.

Instead of sending the whole file you could send an "event message" over the REST api that basically tells the receiver that a new file has arrived for them on the storage at path `/some/where/file.json`.

The receiver could then download the file from the storage (or just read it from a mounted file system), parse it into json again and so on ...